# Best place for if/else piece of code related to custom plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, ajax

Currently this code is placed inside header.php of my theme `wp-content/themes/my-custom-theme/header.php`. It's required for all pages.

```
<?php
include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
$analyticsPluginActive = is_plugin_active('my-custom-plugin/my-custom-plugin.php');
$serviceUrl = '"https://my-custom-url.com"';

if ($analyticsPluginActive) {
    $analyticsPluginOptions = get_option('custom_plugin_settings');
    if (empty($analyticsPluginOptions['use_frontend'])) {
        if (is_admin()) {
            $ajaxUrl = admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=custom_track');
        } else {
            $ajaxUrl = home_url('wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=custom_track');
        }

        $serviceUrl = '"' . $ajaxUrl . '"';
    }
}
?>
var config = {
    serviceUrl: <?php echo $serviceUrl; ?>,
    option1: 'data',
    option2: 'other data'
}
```

Plugin does simple things.

1. If it's active and checkbox is checked on settings page, then use one url for configuration
2. If checkbox is not checked or plugin not active, then use another url for configuration.

I'm not good at wordpress plugin development so my question is: is this code fine? Should i place it somewhere else?

Comment: I would put this code in a plugin and use `wp_localize_script()` to output the JS. Is there a reason why you've chosen to place it in the theme?

Comment: The AJAX URLs are the same. I'm not sure what this code is supposed to accomplish?

Comment: @DaveRomsey actually it should work without plugin too